# Thumbnails not been generated by ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg in my linux box and have this code to generate thumbnails while I upload videos to my webserver. I am trying to save thumbnails in the same folder where I am uploading my videos

php:

```
if (isset($_FILES['attachments'])) 
{
  $msg = "";
  $targetFile = "upload/" . basename($_FILES['attachments']['name'][0]);
  if (file_exists($targetFile))
  $msg = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "File already exists!");
  else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachments']['tmp_name'][0],$targetFile))
  $msg = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "File Has Been Uploaded", "path" => $targetFile);

  $ffmpeg = "upload/";
  $videoFile = $_FILES["attachments"]["tmp_name"];
  $size = "120x90";

    for($num = 1; $num <= 3; $num++)
    {
        $interval = $num * 3;
        shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $videoFile -an -ss $interval -s $size $num.jpg");
        echo "Thumbnail Created! - $num.jpg<br />";
    }
}
```

But I am only getting my uploaded videos in that folder? I find the documentation to use ffmpeg is quite confusing and don't if I am doing it right or not.

Output :

[image]

and when I ran the "ffmpeg" in the command line:

[image]

Comment: You have the PHP code and the `ffmpeg` command. Which is the part not working? Does `ffmpeg` show any errors? Did you check that your `ffmpeg` command works unscripted, in a command-line interface?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard How can I check ffmpeg work in command line?

Comment: yes I have the output from ffmpeg in the command line

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I don't have any error as it's says the thumbnail has created, but I can't see the generated thumbnail in my upload folder

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have updated my question

Comment: The ffmpeg log is text, so please copy and paste text instead of making screenshots of text. I'm not looking for the output of the plain ffmpeg command, but I need to see the output from the actual command being issued by the script. So echo the ffmpeg command the script makes, copy this command, open terminal, navigate to the directory that the script is running in, paste the ffmpeg command and execute it, copy the resulting log, then [edit] your question to include this log and the command that made it.